# Probability of a certain card being UR, SR, R, or N

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, odds

There are 200 packs in a box, and there are 3 cards in each pack (600 cards total) and you must buy one pack (3 cards) at a time. A pack can contain: An UR (10 total), a SR (24 total), a R (192 total), or N (374).

A pack can only hold one UR or SR at a time, however there can be any number of R or N in a pack. Also, each pack must contain at least one 1 UR,SR, or R.

What are the odds/probability of drawing each one of these (UR,SR,R,N) in the first pack (out of 200)?

Comment: Please feel free to add the self-study tag and explain what you have tried so far

Comment: Can a pack contain both a UR and an SR, or only one of each?  And is the question what is the odds of getting any of those in one single pack?

Comment: Also, since a pack only holds 3 cards, and you're asking to draw 4 cards, it sounds like you are getting multiple packs? So the question would make more sense if you ask, "what's the chance of drawing at least one of each UR,SR,R,N from $n$ packs, where $n\geq 2$."

Comment: Is this an exercise for a class? What to do you mean by "drawing" here -- do you mean "opening a single pack" or "looking at one card" or something else? What are we assuming about the distribution of cards in the box? What are we assuming about "drawing"?

Comment: @MatthewDrury - A pack, consisting of three cards and can only contain up to 1 UR or 1 SR. The question is, what are the odds getting each. So what are the odds of getting one UR out of 200, or one SR out of 200, and so on.

Comment: There are multiple packs, but I am asking what are the odds at the starting point of 200 for each, UR,SR,R,N. So yes, at least one of each @AlexR.

Comment: Would the probability of an UR then be 1 in 600, or 1 in 20?

Comment: @Derek Not sure if this is a helpful comment, but on this site be aware that **probability** and **odds** are two related but different quantities: $\text{Odds}(x) = \frac{\text{Probability}(x)}{1-\text{Probability}(x)}$.